# Ember Data not Serializing Date field properly

Tags: ember-data

According the docs

> Please note: Ember Data serializes and deserializes dates according to
>   ISO 8601. For example: 2014-05-27T12:54:01

I get from the server JSON like this:

```
"createDate" : "2014-08-07T22:30:58.438Z"
```

My model looks like this:

```
createDate: DS.attr('date'),
```

At this point I have a valid javascript date stored in createDate, however, when I save the model, my ember app is serializing as follows:

```
"createDate" : "Thu, 07 Aug 2014 22:30:58 GMT"
```

Why is this?  I would expect it to serialize as 2014-08-07T22:30:58 as the docs mention.

Comment: @kristjanreinhold Because ember supports a date datatype, why would I use a String instead of a native javascript date.  That makes no sense.

Comment: Looks like something that needs to be reported as an issue. To change the format override [DateTransform](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.DateTransform.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed on master by https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1985 and should work for you if you use Ember-Data canary